# $P({X^{-1}(x)}) = p$ for all $x$ then Field is finite

Tags: probability-theory, solution-verification, proof-writing

### Notation:

- $\Omega$ denotes a $\sigma-$Field
- $X$ is a function onto $\Omega$
- $X^{-1}$ is pre-image
- $P(\cdot)$ is a probability measure
- $X^{-1}$ is also a $\sigma-$Field, as a consequence of properties of preimage

### Claim:

$P(\{ X^{-1}(x)\})=p$  $\;\forall x \in \Omega$
Then $\Omega$ has finite number of points

### Logic:

By Definition of PDF:
$k \cdot \sum P(\{ X^{-1}(x)\})=1$

Thus, this sum should be definite, as in $k$ should be finite, hence the preimage should be finite ,ie, $\Omega$ should have finite number of points.

Is This reasoning correct?

### Edit:

I don't think the original question says anything about probability distributions.
So considering $P$ as only a probability measure:
$\cup A_i = \Omega$ for some $A_i$

By Kolmogorov additivity axiom:
$P(X^{-1}( \cup A_i)) = \sum P(X^{-1}(A_i))$

$= P(X^{-1}(\Omega)) = 1$

Hence number of elements of $\Omega$ is $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$n\cdot p=1$

Comment: What is $k$ in the last sum?

Comment: Just A constant

Comment: Not "Just A constant", but "just a mistake".  The sum of probabilities over a set of independent events that covers all possible outcomes will be $1$. This is part of the definition of probability itself. It is not the sum multiplied by some $k$, but the sum itself that is $1$. A big hint that you have failed to properly explain why this is true is that you didn't make any use of the key condition that was given: that all the probabilities  are $p$. In your edit, you add an unnecessary "proof" of a definition, then skip the argument you need to make.

Comment: Hint: there are only two cases: $p = 0$ and $p>0$. Show that in neither case is it possible for the sum to be $1$ if $\Omega$ is infinite.

Comment: Yeah, i understood, being new to measure theory, i kind of messed up between probability distribution of a random variable and preimage. But, thanks